# CSS & HTML5: Position a <footer> at the bottom of the page? no wrapper?

Tags: css, html, footer

the age-old problem. I need to position a `<footer>` Element at the bottom of the page. However i don't have a wrapper div.

I'm do have the following stucture…

```
<body>
<header>
<section id="content">
<footer>
</body>
```

Is there an easy way to push the footer to the bottom if the content is not high enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is still the best way to get a footer to stick to the bottom of the page:

http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/footerStickAlt/

Answer (score 17):

Came by this question, and thought I'd post what I've come across. Seems like the ideal way to me.

CSS:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav></nav>
    <article>Lorem ipsum...</article>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

All credit goes to http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/

Comment: I LOVE this option.  So nice.  Also if you are using bootstrap be careful not to confuse `.footer` class with `footer` element.

Answer (score 10):

Make it `position: fixed; bottom: 0, height: xxx`? Of course, then it'd overlap any content should the page actually go past the bottom of the window. Perhaps some JS to detect "short" content and set css as appropriate.

Comment: Just set a bottom margin at the content that is equal to the height of the footer

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your code this may not work, but I'd suggest setting your `body` to `position:relative;` and then setting the `footer` to `position:absolute;` and `bottom:0`. In theory it won't overlap things then.

Answer (score 1):

i had made a jsfiddle before, check out this http://jsfiddle.net/kuyabiye/K5pYe/ try resizin the result window, if the content will overflow the scroll will be seen.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works great for me. Sticky to bottom, no overlap with content, no need for a wrapper.

https://jsfiddle.net/vq1kcedv/

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Footer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>Link1 Link2</nav>
    <article>content</article>
    <footer>Copyright</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html, body {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body:after {
    line-height: 100px; /* height of footer */
    white-space: pre;
    content: "\A";
}

footer {  
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px; /* height of footer */
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: -100px; /* height of footer */
}
```

Comment: Worked great for me. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/YMtSq/)

**HTML**

```
<header>

</header>

<section id="content">

</section>

<footer>

</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  height: 100%;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

  var footer  = $('footer'),
      footHgt = $('footer').outerHeight(),
      bodyHgt = $('body').height();

  footer
    .css({
      position: 'absolute',
      left: '0',
      top: bodyHgt - footHgt + 'px'
     });

  $(window).resize(function() {

    var footer  = $('footer'),
        footHgt = $('footer').outerHeight(),
        bodyHgt = $('body').height();   

    footer
     .css({
       position: 'absolute',
       left: '0',
       top: bodyHgt - footHgt + 'px'
     }); 

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but I wanted to provide my own solution (with javascript) :

```
/* css */
footer { width:100%; bottom:0; }

/* javascript */
if ($("body").height() < $(window).height()) {
    document.querySelector('footer').style = 'position:absolute;'
}
```

It should work with any kind of footer of any size.

EDIT : alternative solution ( no need for css) :

```
/* footer */
if ($("body").height() < $(window).height()) { /* if the page is not long enouth, let's put some more margin to the footer */
    var height = $(document).height() - $("body").height();
    document.querySelector("footer").style.marginTop = height + "px";
}
```